# Android RelativeLayout working in LayoutEditor but breaking on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

For the TitleBar I have a RelativeLayout, which should display two buttons on the right side, and two TextViews on the left side. I got the layout code working in the Editor, but on the device it always breaks down.

On the image you can see a Screenshot from the Layout Editor and from the device (runs like this on multiple devices).

[image: Relative Layout Editor vs Device]

Here is the Layout Code I'm using:
- I know I just can dump in LinearLayouts, but this should be possible with RelativeLayout?
- I used the "toStartOf" properties because I don't want to overflow the icons with text if the text might be longer.
- Bonus Question: how can I center the two labels vertical, so that they are also centered if I only have a title and set the subtitle visibility to GONE

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_content_padding"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            tools:src="@drawable/account"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/toolbar_right_button"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_notifications"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/toolbar_left_button"
            android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_medium"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:text="Title "/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            tools:text="Subtitle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **ConstraintLayout** would solve your problem. It keeps your layout *flat*, and also *centers your text layouts vertically* (and maintains it even after you 'remove' the subtitle).

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_right_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_content_padding"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/account" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_content_padding"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_right_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_notifications" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_family_medium"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/toolbar_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar_left_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:text="Title " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_title"
        tools:text="Subtitle" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem with `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/toolbar_subtitle"` because the id is used before the element is declared. If i move the elements around it works but there is still an error because the text overlaps the Icons. The `layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf`seems not to put it on the left side but alignit on the right side of the icon.

Comment: ok, with the current design library the constraint layout works perfectly fine :)

Comment: @scholt, even with the previous version, changing it to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"` would have worked (:

Answer (score 0):

I have made it simple so it wont get messy:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

There are high chances that if You add a lot of elements and tools to the layout it will get messy, try to keep it simple and You will find what caused the problem.

Comment: cool, but the main reason why I used the RelativeLayout is because I wanted to keep the View hierarchy flat. If I use nested layouts I can also use LinearLayouts but I would like to avoid the nesting at all

Comment: @scholt I have edited for a flat RLayout, works fine on emulator.

Comment: I should say that if You position the gui elements wrong and mess with sizes it might get messy too. Try to add a size for image buttons and just change the text size, I am pretty sure that will work fine as long as the textview fields wont get way bigger and then the layout might just put the element above each other because it cant wrap the content in a proper way.